# Clase abstracta PHP

Tags: php

Hola tengo que realizar una clase de Empresa, pero usando el metodo abstracto, por lo poco que he podido leer he entendido que se maneja masomenos asi, pero debe haber algun error en mi codigo porque me sale pantalla en blanco :/

```
<?php
/**
* Creando la clase principal que vendra a ser la abstracta
*/
abstract class Empresa
{
public $propietario = '';
public $finalidad = '';
function __construct($propietario,$presupuesto,$finalidad)
{
    $this-> propietario = $propietario;
    $this-> finalidad = $finalidad;
}

abstract public function setPropietario($propietario);

abstract public function setFinalidad($finalidad);

}

/**
* Clase extendida para empresa privada
 */
 class EmpresaPrivada extends Empresa
{
public function setFinalidad()
{
    $this-> finalidad = "lucrativa";
    echo "La empresa tiene una finalidad: ".$this-> finalidad;
}
public function setPropietario($propietario)
{
    $this-> propietario = "privado";
    echo "La empresa tiene una propietario: ".$this-> propietario;
}

}

/**
* Clase extendida para empresa publica
*/
class EmpresaPublica extends Empresa
{
public function setFinalidad()
{
    $this-> finalidad = "de ayuda";
    echo "La empresa tiene una finalidad: ".$this-> finalidad;
}
public function setPropietario($propietario)
{
    $this-> propietario = "publico";
    echo "La empresa tiene una propietario: ".$this-> propietario;
}
}

/**
 * Clase extendida para empresa mixta
 */
 class EmpresaMixta extends Empresa
{
public function setFinalidad()
{
    $this-> finalidad = "ambas";
    echo "La empresa tiene una finalidad: ".$this-> finalidad;
}
public function setPropietario($propietario)
{
    $this-> propietario = "mixto";
    echo "La empresa tiene una propietario: ".$this-> propietario;
}
 }

/**
 * Clase extendida para empresa autogestion
*/
class EmpresaAutogestion extends Empresa
{
public function setFinalidad()
{
    $this-> finalidad = "de apoyo";
    echo "La empresa tiene una finalidad: ".$this-> finalidad;
}
public function setPropietario($propietario)
{
    $this-> propietario = "propio";
    echo "La empresa tiene una propietario: ".$this-> propietario;
}

}

$obj = new EmpresaPrivada();
$obj->setFinalidad();
```

o en todo caso, cual es la manera correcta de usar este tipo de funciones, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿No sería mejor usar interfaces para esto?

Comment: Creo que si, pero el trabajo es usar el patron FACTORY para resolverlo :/

Answer (score 0):

El error que sale es:

> Fatal error: Declaration of EmpresaPrivada::setFinalidad() must be
>   compatible with Empresa::setFinalidad($finalidad) in
>   /var/www/html/test.inc.php on line 16

Lo extraño, es que he tenido que poner las clases extendidas en un otro fichero y hacer un include, porque todo en el mismo fichero no mostraba error.

Y la solución es declarar `public function setFinalidad()` compatible con la clase abstracta, es decir `public function setFinalidad($finalidad)`

(edito)

Míralo aqui: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3f43e8ea2f9c720f39f3e9d9001fe8b5ec47f2b

Y dependiendo de la versión, lo estricta que sea, te permitirá usarla así:

```
$obj = new EmpresaPrivada();
$obj->setFinalidad();
```

o te dará error y tendrás que hacer:

```
$obj = new EmpresaPrivada('propietario','presupuesto','finalidad');
$obj->setFinalidad('finalidad');
```

Es decir, el mayor problema que tienes es si declaras las funciones con parámetros o sin ellos, debes usar lo mismo en la clase abstracta y en la extendida. Que te salte error o pantalla en blanco, parece ser, depende mucho de tu configuración particular.

¿Me expliqué ahora mejor?

Comment: include y require manejan diferente el reporte de errores, include por lo general tira un warning y continúa donde un require daría un fatal error

Comment: No, lo que quise decir es que si declaro todas las clases en el mismo fichero no sale mensaje de error (aún forzando explicitamente en el código mediante ini_set() y error_reporting() ) solo se queda la pantalla en blanco, pero si pongo las clases secundarias en un fichero aparte (usando include o require) SI me salta el error mencionado (Fatal error: ..... ).

Comment: Aun cambiando a public function setFinalidad() sigue saliendo pantalla en blanco :/

Comment: revisa mi ultima edición, añado ejemplo y aclaraciones